# Scroll to Div from bottom of nav not top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so I have a scroll button (#scroll) in header that when clicked scrolls  the next div (.scroll-up) to the top of the page. However, I would like for that div to scroll to the bottom of the nav element instead of to the top of the page. How could I do this?

```
$("#scroll").click(function(){
    $(this).preventDefault;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scroll-down").offset().top
    }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML too?

Comment: What's `.scroll-down`? Is that where you want the page to scroll to?

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0633qrf3/)

`$(this).preventDefault` is wrong, you use `e.preventDefault();` where `e` is the event, which is set in the function declaration as the first argument.

You didn't provide any HTML, so using this as an example

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
    </ul>
<nav>
<!-- content -->
<a id="scroll" href="#">^ TOP</a>
```

The bottom of `#nav` would be `$('#nav').height() + $('#nav').offset().top`

```
$("#scroll").click(function(e){ // <-- variable for event is set here
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#nav').height() + $('#nav').offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.scroll-down element should be at the bottom.
In other words, `scrollTop: $(".scroll-down").offset().top` will scroll the document to that element. And make sure you have only on `.scroll-down` element.

Check the fiddle. click on div '.advertising' will scroll to bottom of document.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="advertising" id="scroll">Advertising</div>
    <div class="header">Header</div>


    <div class="slideshow">Slideshow</div>

    <div class="advertising">Advertising</div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="content">

        <h1>Content Area</h1>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.

Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.

In varius sodales odio sed dapibus. Ut ut orci quis ante hendrerit dignissim. Quisque at enim eget turpis adipiscing molestie. Sed sed nulla ante, sed pellentesque urna. Fusce fermentum, erat in consectetur elementum, ante nibh scelerisque dui, eget dictum urna felis nec dui. Quisque felis libero, placerat in mattis non, scelerisque nec nulla. Suspendisse potenti. In mauris lectus, pretium adipiscing dictum ut, ultrices nec enim. Fusce mauris nibh, auctor eget euismod egestas, vehicula quis augue. Sed eget tellus pharetra ligula adipiscing suscipit quis eu elit.

Duis tristique, mauris lacinia posuere sollicitudin, tellus nulla lacinia nulla, eget vulputate quam leo in nisi. Phasellus cursus, purus non accumsan ultricies, sem nibh accumsan elit, eget malesuada nulla purus sit amet quam. Fusce tempus justo vel turpis euismod aliquet. Integer pulvinar lacus vel diam consequat ut porttitor ante tempus. Curabitur sit amet nibh at libero accumsan volutpat. Nullam laoreet, metus non posuere faucibus, massa sapien lobortis justo, quis tempus purus orci semper nunc. Sed id sapien turpis. Vestibulum rutrum lacus sed augue mattis vel dignissim mi consectetur. Cras eget eros neque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum convallis commodo sem, ac vehicula nisi fermentum a. Curabitur scelerisque auctor pellentesque. Proin non arcu ante, a ornare tortor. Maecenas faucibus porta orci, posuere facilisis odio consequat quis. Pellentesque placerat laoreet justo, sed eleifend sem consequat eget. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus semper. Cras congue dapibus massa at vehicula. In eros libero, adipiscing quis vestibulum id, commodo et dui. Curabitur semper aliquam adipiscing. Suspendisse et urna nulla. Sed iaculis vehicula adipiscing. Sed scelerisque, libero nec aliquam varius, quam mi posuere augue, ut tempor metus eros quis risus.     

    </div>

    <div id="left-tab-col">

        <a class="tab-button" style="top:10000px">Tab</a>   

    </div>

    <div id="right-tab-col">

        <a class="tab-button" style="top:10000px">Tab</a>           

    </div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper">



    <div class="footer">Footer</div>

    <div class="nav">Footer Nav</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$("#scroll").click(function(){
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".nav").offset().top
  }, 1000)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SGCHt/487/

Answer (score 0):

First off, i 'd like to point out your prevention of the click action or button action you have linked it to, is not typed correctly, thus is will run that action.

Further, your code is a bit incomplete, due to the fact we miss some html, but your question is further clear enough to give an interpretation.

It depends on a bit where you wanna go on the page and how to get there, but the most common way to do this is use an achor and an id corresponding to that. You can use that item to go to a specific div.

So for instance if I click on an item like this

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="nav" style="height: 1px;">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>`
```

It will jump to an html object with the id `profile` on the same page, however, for a scrolling effect, you can add something like this.

```
$("#nav ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var hash = this.hash;

   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
     }, 300, function(){
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });   
});
```

As you see here, the object (`e` in the function decleration) is prevented, not the `this`.

My point is that this will animate it as a scrolling animation. There are a couple of animations you can play with as well.

`e.preventDefault();` can also be swapped with a `return false;` if you wish to not use it. It would be something then like this.

```
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500, 'swing');
    return false;
});
```

(that is a code of making it scroll back to the top btw)

More information about the scrolltop function you can find in the Jquery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Alright this ended up working for me. Thanks!

```
$("#scroll").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var nav = $(".nav-bar").height() + $(".nav-bar").offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".scroll-down").offset().top - nav
  }, 1000)
});
```